# Perl and Ruby modules in the same repository?

Tags: ruby, perl, git, module, rubygems

I've started working on a new Perl module and I've decided that I want to make a Ruby version of it as well (once I finish the Perl version). Do people tend to make separate repositories for each language? Or put them in the same repository?

I can easily see how the two sets of code are different enough to be treated as separate projects. But at the same time it's the same functionality written in two languages, so from that perspective it seems like a single project with two language ports.

What's considered best practice in this situation?

FWIW, I'm using git.

**EDIT**: I should be more clear here. These aren't modules in the sense of `git submodules`. They're modules that will be submitted to CPAN and RubyGems. Users of this project will likely be installing it via `cpan` or `gem` and then using/requiring it in the normal fashion.

Comment: If you go the separate repo way, don't forget that each repo can make the other a remote, allowing you to see the other and its branches as remote branches

Answer (score 1):

In the course of my group's research, we have a couple repos, some with different technologies in each.  We divide the repos by research question and checkout only the projects we are working on, with the repos having a uniform hierarchal directory structure that is the same for all projects. Since we already know the repo directory structural, running scripts and finding data becomes much easier.

I would recommend taking the same approach.  The higher the division between the two technologies, the easier it will be to contribute to one of them without being confused by the presence of the other.

In the end ask yourself this: If I were to add another language, would I still keep it in one repo?  If the answer is yes, keep doing what you're doing. If not, keep these libraries in two separate repos and manage the projects and contributers distinctly.

Comment: That's the very question that I'm hung up on. In previous projects, adding a wrapper/binding for another language was done in the same repo. But it seems that Perl and Ruby modules/gems are often organized as one module/gem per repo. What happens if I add Python as well? Three repos seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

my experience in this kind of case is to have 2 smaller git repos for each of the modules and either cloning one branch into the consumer projects repo makes it quite simple.  another way is to create a naked clone from the module's repo into the consumer projects repo, then just keep updating it as each module's development progresses.  the consumer project should ignore the injected repos.

once other dev clones module A, and/or B, then he/she can just push to consumer project, as permissions allow. this is either a pro or a con depends.